# Visual Studio crashes when locking computer or starting another instance

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

I have the problem that Visual Studio 2013 crashes when I lock the computer or start another instance of Visual Studio. 
I use Visual Studio 2013 with latest patches applied. I always start Visual Studio as Admin.

This seems to only happen with a certain big solution. This problem did not occur to me with other solutions.

I tried to delete the solution and make a clean checkout from TFS, but Visual Studio still crashes.

I know this is not much information, but do you have any idea how to fix this or how to what else I could check?

**Additional Information: This still happens even with Visual Studio 2015 on a fresh Windows 8.1 installation...**

Here's the error:

[image]

Comment: Is it OK without the plugins?

Comment: I uninstalled the plugins, but VS keeps crashing.

Comment: I have the same problem!  This explains the problem in another way.  I have not tried to downgrade NVIDIA drivers yet.  https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1272232/ntdll-dll-crash-in-visual-studio-2013-on-windows-8-1-enterprise-on-laptop-when-using-a-dual-display-setup.  It's happening to me with Visual Studio 2013 and 2015.  I have ReSharper 9, so I'm glad to know it is not that.

Comment: FYI The crash happens when you lock, not when you return from lock based on the time stamp I saw in **Event Viewer**.  Event Viewer error:  `Faulting application name: devenv.exe, version: 14.0.23107.0, time stamp: 0x559b7ead
Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 6.3.9600.18007, time stamp: Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll`

Comment: I really needed to ask my own question, so I did here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34072829/visual-studio-2013-and-2015-crash-when-locking-windows-8-1

Answer (score 0):

Use the following steps to solve the issue:

Source: http://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/entries/24765142-Visual-Studio-with-ReSharper-is-freezing-and-or-crashing

I would copy the solution with quotation but as you can see, there is a lot of text to edit.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the link, sadly it is not related to ReSharper. I uninstalled it and VS still crashes

Comment: Try to open vs in safe mode - devenv /safemode, lock your PC and see if still happen...

Comment: if previous comment doesn't help, Tty to delete the ".v12.suo" file and try to open the solution again.

Comment: Already done, as I mentioned in the question I deleted the complete workspace and pulled a new version from the VCS where there are no suo files

Answer (score 0):

Start Visual Studio using the `/log` switch. Then check the created log file for warnings and errors:

```
%APPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\ActivityLog.xml
```

If you use a Web Browser to view the file, it will be nicely formatted, due to the accompanying xsl-sheet.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, there are only a few Warnings like this: `Unexpected system error mode before loading package [...]` and one error: `The color &apos;Popup&apos; in category &apos;de7b1121-99a4-4708-aedf-15f40c9b332f&apos; does not exist.` Seems to be unrelated.

Comment: And what about the log entries just before the crash?