# Visual Studio 2013 and 2015 Crash when locking Windows 8.1

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

Visual Studio dies/crashes after resuming from lock <kbd>Win-L</kbd> with this error screen.  This seems to happen only when docked to dual monitor.

[image]

#### Problem details shows:

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: devenv.exe
  Application Version:  14.0.23107.0
  Fault Module Name:    StackHash_f6a7
  Fault Module Version: 6.3.9600.18007
  Exception Code:   c0000374
  Exception Offset: PCH_1F_FROM_ntdll+0x0003CA2C
  OS Version:   6.3.9600.2.0.0.256.48
  Locale ID:    1033
```

### What I have:

1. Windows 8.1
2. Visual Studio 2013 and 2015
3. ReSharper 9

### Things I have tried:

1. Run DELL Command Update.  Drivers are all up to date.
2. Upgrade display drivers.  All up to date.
3. Use Visual Studio 2015.
4. Run as Administrator.
5. Downgrade NVIDIA driver per [this MSFT Ticket](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1272232/ntdll-dll-crash-in-visual-studio-2013-on-windows-8-1-enterprise-on-laptop-when-using-a-dual-display-setup).  I have an NVIDIA Quadro K1100M.  Driver version from 10.18.13.5382 to 348.07 (9.18.13.4807).
6. Event Viewer.  It does not show much info (Below), but it does indicate that the crash happened when I locked, not when I resumed from lock.

```
    Faulting application name: devenv.exe, version: 14.0.23107.0
    Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 6.3.9600.18007
    Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe 
    Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
```

Comment: You could try to debug it also. With a little luck you'll find it hosed in a 3rd party stack frame.

Comment: What about locking from the start menu instead of Win+L?

Comment: ... or indeed, running `rundll32.exe user32.dll, LockWorkStation` which will also lock the machine.

Comment: Still happens when locking from start menu.

Comment: Upgrade to Windows 10?

Comment: @FraserCrosbie I'm on Windows 10 and I experience this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it.  Indeed downgrading the video card driver did the trick.  Here is exactly the driver I downloaded.  I had downgraded twice because I really didn't know which one to pick.

- Downgrade driver to 341.61-quadro-grid-desktop-notebook-win8-win7-64bit-international-whql.exe.

In the end, **[this link](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1272232/ntdll-dll-crash-in-visual-studio-2013-on-windows-8-1-enterprise-on-laptop-when-using-a-dual-display-setup)** helped the most.  I wish MS would re-open it.  Search for "**driver**" in the page.

PS: Seems kind of dumb that this question and answer is really not related to coding, but Visual Studio is a pretty commonly used IDE.  I only hope this answer helps *someone* in the future.

Comment: Unfortunately that link is now dead and there's no recorded backup on archive.org

Comment: Bummer @TylerH.  I have no idea where I could find it again, but at least stack overflow got your back!